# HTML Scraping with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, screen-scraping

I use a simple javascript script, in a batch file, to download audio and video - radio and tv shows - from the BBC iPlayer.

Part of the script extracts data from the BBC's xml pages.

I now want to try extracting data from a html page. Can anyone point me to a javascript method for extracting data from an ordinary .htm or .html page?

I'm anxious to keep things simple, by having a javascript routine which I can include in a html page on my website, so I'm only interested in javascript solutions. Thanks.

Edit, 24 Aug -

The BBC's html pages don't respond to the Javascript scripts which successfully  parse their xml pages.

I use a simple javascript to interrogate xml, based on this -

function loadXML() {
 xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
 xmlDoc.async = false;
 xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = readXML;
 xmlDoc.load(url);
}

Comment: Some (but nowhere near all) _HTML_ will successfully be parsed by _XML_ parsers

Comment: I'm not asking this question in order to pirate a site. What I want to do is extract some limited programme details from the BBC's radio and tv schedules, in connection with recording occasional radio broadcasts. For example, I'd like to be able to extract and store in a text file the dates of previous broadcasts of the show, which are invariably html elements, e.g. from this page: http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b007nf83/broadcasts

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kinda vague. I think there may be two ways to get this done:
1. apply RegExp to match patterns
2. import the html into a dom simulator and walk the tree to find the data ( I assume you using nodejs )

Comment: Is there an example, anywhere online, that I could look at to understand how this is achieved in either case?